# UIApplication.shared is unavailable

Tags: swift, xcode, onesignal, podfile

I've been trying to add OneSignal to my proyect, the error appears on my other pods that I'm working with when I add `target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
end` to my Podfile.

I've also tried to change the Require Only App-Extension-Safe API values and still no success

Does anyone had the same problem and solved it?